# Image in a listview not clickable

Tags: android

I can open the app but I am not able to click on the image .. what wrong I am doing ?

the below is the adapter

```
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter1(this, R.layout.screen_list1,
imageArry);
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleViewActivity.class);
           // Pass image index
           i.putExtra("id", position);
           startActivity(i);
           } });
```

this is the activity main

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Latest" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

        android:background="#B29090" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Recomanded" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#4A9C67" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is ContactImageAdapter1 class

```
package com.example.sqlfirst;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactImageAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
public ContactImageAdapter1(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = context;
this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
ImageHolder holder = null;
if(row == null)
{
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new ImageHolder();
holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
row.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
}
Contact picture = data.get(position);
holder.txtTitle.setText(picture ._name);
//convert byte to bitmap take from contact class
byte[] outImage=picture._image;
ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
return row;
}
static class ImageHolder
{
ImageView imgIcon;
TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding onClicklistener to image directly?

Comment: I am not working with the image , i am working with listview directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have somewhere the ContactImageAdapter1 class.
You have to attach an [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) at the [getView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method, after you load your ImageView from the list item layout.

So, your getView method have to be something like this :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  ImageHolder holder = null;
  if(row == null)
  {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new ImageHolder();
   holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
   holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
   // lets attach the click listener!
   holder.imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent i = new Intent(((Activity)context), SingleViewActivity.class);  // or whatever method you have to get the context
       // Pass image index
       i.putExtra("id", position);
       startActivity(i);
      }
   });
   row.setTag(holder);
  }else
  {
    holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
  }
  Contact picture = data.get(position);
  holder.txtTitle.setText(picture ._name);
  //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class
  byte[] outImage=picture._image;
  ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new    
  ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
  Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
  holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
  return row;
}
```

Comment: yes I have getview in the adapter .. where should I put it ?

Comment: like this is corretct ? Intent i = new Intent(ContactImageAdapter1 .getview(), SingleViewActivity.class);

Comment: No, this is totally wrong. If you want post your code of getView method. The listener will be attached inside the getView body at the ImageView. If you want to open the intent only when the ImageView will be clicked , you have to remove the OnItemClickListener from details and let the other ImageView listener to do the job

Comment: ok ill post ContactImageAdapter1  adapter , i was stuck on this all day I am not able to set the onclicklistner

Comment: I am having this erro The method setOnClickListenerOnClickListener() is undefined for the type ImageView .. by the way i am not using imageview in the xml , i am using listview

Comment: Okay ill check it but in my xml i am not calling imageview .. i am just calling a list .. is that correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79997/discussion-between-karvoynistas-and-moudiz).

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739336/setonitemclicklistener-doenst-work-when-add-a-button) solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

go into the root of your custom Layout (screen_list1) and add this:

```
android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants"
```

It would be probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener` implementation if you are using Activity/Fragment from appcompat library.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have made `ImageHolder` class a static class inside the `Adapter` class this thus forces DVM to create only one copy for all the items in the `ListView` hence the problem